# Spring Data Rest id's or link href

Tags: json, spring-data, pojo, spring-rest

I am using Spring data rest and I am facing the following:

I have an entity

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long roleId;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

}
```

I am using RepositoryRestResource:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long> {

    Role findByRoleId(@Param("roleId") final Long roleId);

    Role findByName(@Param("roleName") final String roleName);
}
```

When I make a call via the browser (http://localhost:9000/roles/1) I see this

```
{
name: "ROLE_SOMETHING",
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:9000/roles/1"
},
role: {
href: "http://localhost:9000/roles/1"
},
users: {
href: "http://localhost:9000/roles/1/users"
}
}
}
```

The client uses

```
   ResponseEntity<RoleView> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:9000/roles/1", RoleView.class);
   RoleView body = forEntity.getBody();
   System.out.println(body.getName());
```

RoleView is a representation of the Role entity but on the caller client side.

Now the roleId is not present in the json response. I am not sure why because I am not using the default name id.

I would like the RoleView object to have the id in some kind of way. Either via roleId or maybe via the link _self -> href.

I would prefer the link _self way because that seems closer to the json response instead of exposingId's.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For now I am going for the solution:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Role.class);
    }
}
```

Though I am looking forward to other types of solutions